# Adjust Bias Term in Final Layer of Neural Net Using Tensorflow v2 after Training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

Is it possible to make adjustments to the bias term in the final layer of a Neural Net after training the model using TFv2?  Here is an example of my model:

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras

def simple_model(input_size, 
                 layer_1_size,
                 layer_2_size,
                 number_of_classes
                 ):

input_layer = keras.layers.Input(input_size)

layer_1 = keras.layers.Dense(layer_1_size, activation='relu')(input_layer)
layer_2 = keras.layers.Dense(layer_2_size, activation='relu')(layer_1)
output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(number_of_classes, activation='softmax')(layer_2)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
return model
```

I would like to essentially train the model above and make  an adjustment to the bias term in the output layer after the model is trained but before using the model to make predictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can modify the last bias of the network with an array of zeros

```
model.fit(...)

new_bias = np.zeros(model.output.shape[-1])
model.set_weights(model.get_weights()[:-1] + [new_bias])

# final check
model.get_weights()[-1]
```